# How to add Google Analytics parameters by default to all buttons?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

In a Sitecore project I have added button implementations with Google Analytics support multiple times. The Google Analytics parameters (e.g. category, action and label) are also several times stored as fields in Sitecore templates.

I think this is not the way to go. I'm searching for a more general solution, for example a button component with Google Analytics integrated. Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks a lot.

Jordy

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics tagging implementation is an aspect of presentation and not content hence we typically use Rendering Parameters Template to add additional fields to the rendering itself than the content item. The assumption is that you typically limit the use of one tag per component. If you have not used Rendering Parameters Template in the past, here is a quick example http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2012/12/sitecore-rendering-parameter-templates/